# Switching between Filter views using apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-filter-view

I would like to create a custom menu with items to switch between filter views on particular sheet. Is there any way?
I need filter views, because of sorting and filtering but still keeping edit option. Filter function doesn't work due to that fact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Filter View doesn't have support on apps Script yet
It's an old [feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-apps-script-issues/issues/detail?id=524&q=saved%20filter&colspec=Stars%20Opened%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Summary%20Component%20Owner)

Comment: Thanks for info. It's a pity. Let's hope for future.

Comment: In new feature request tracker - https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36761488 and https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/73785768

Comment: This answer is obsolete

Comment: The [mentioned feature request link is marked as Fixed](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753410), but there is [another feature request named Integration of Filter Views in Spreadsheet Service](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753410). Maybe the first one is marked as fixed because the following comment in the thread: _Yesterday we released some new functionality that makes it possible to manipulate filters with Apps Script:_ (...) _https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/filter_ I think it's possible to filter by using that functionality

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to use a custom menu to switch between filter views as Google Apps Script hasn't methods to access the filter views settings (i.e. activate a filter view) for the active user.

One option is to use a custom menu to show a dialog or sidebar to show the instructions to use filter views to the active user.

Resources

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets
- https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it right, the simple solution/workaround for you would be to make custom menu which reopens the spreadsheet with the filter view id in url.
GAS doesn't allow to open new browser window, as far as I know, but there is a workaround with dialog box for that too.

Answer (score -4):

It is possible to access and edit filters using the [Advanced Sheets service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets), as seen in [this example](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/36753410#comment157).

Comment: The referred example is about filters, not filter views.

Comment: Hi @Rubén, it _is_ possible somehow through the Advanced Sheets Service, but I still haven't wrap my head around how exactly to do it. Here's the API doc, https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters. Class `Sheets` in Apps Script Advanced Sheets API contains methods called `newFilterView()` and `newAddFilterViewRequest()`, but both of them don't take any arguments, so I still can't neither find any examples of usage nor understand how to use them on my own. I see your name a lot in GS answers, maybe you would know?

Comment: @grreeenn I don't remember have seen any example so I suggest you to post a new question.