# Apps Script, figure out which of the Sheets FilterViews is active

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Context:** Users interact with a Gsheet using Filter Views (they do it in parallel, hence filters are not an option). My functionality is based on active cell identification:

```
var row = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(mainSheetName).getActiveRange().getRowIndex();
```

which gets fooled when certain functionalities of filter views are applied (for instance, sorting). Consequently, I want to control what user does with filter views and prevent them from doing certain things.

**Question-related stuff:** I am writing a script in AppsScript which would take into account active FilterViews (**FV** later on). I have found out how to access FV functionality from the Sheets API. However, the FV instance does not have an "active" attribute making it impossible to directly check if a certain FV is applied for the user. Hence, the question: how do I check which of the FilterViews is applied to the sheet?

**A workaround** I have identified is getting a list of FVs present on some method execution (which does not work for OnOpen()), then tracking changes - if a new FV is created, then assume that it is the active one. *Drawback:* It doesn't allow spotting activations of the existing filters.

**Another workaround** is removing all FVs before user starts interacting with addon (after `OnOpen()` though), then the next newly created FV is likely to be the active one. If I delete all FVs for myself, the active FVs for other users do not disappear, hence their workflow is not disturbed.

Here is the code for the last workaround that does the job for me:

```
  function checkFilterViews() {
  const spreadsheetId = "sheet-id-here" // Please set the Spreadsheet ID.
  const sheetName = "tab_name_here!A:A"; // Please set the sheet name.

  // 1. Retrieve the settings of the filter view (`filterViews`) you want to use.
  const res1 = Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(spreadsheetId, { ranges: [sheetName] });
  const sheetId = res1.sheets[0].properties.sheetId;
  const filterViews = res1.sheets[0].filterViews;

  // Checking if FVs exist
  if (filterViews!==undefined){
      for (var i=0;i<filterViews.length;i++){
            // Check if there is sorting in FVs (I want to prevent users from sorting)
            if (filterViews[i].sortSpecs!=null){
            Browser.msgBox(filterViews[i].title+" contains SORTING and sorting breaks things. Please do not sort.");
            delFilterViews(); // Delete all FVs
            break
          }
          // Check if the filter is applied to column names and not some arbitrary row
          if (filterViews[0].range["startRowIndex"]!=1.0){
            Browser.msgBox(filterViews[i].title+" is applied incorrectly. Please select Row 2, and then create a new FilterView.");
            delFilterViews();
            break
          }
      }
  }

  return filterViews
}

function delFilterViews() {
  var ssId = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getId();
  Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(
    {
      requests: Sheets.Spreadsheets.get(ssId, {
        ranges: 'replace_with_sheet_name', //Sheet in which filterviews are present
        fields: 'sheets/filterViews/filterViewId',
      }).sheets[0].filterViews.map(function(e) {
        return { deleteFilterView: { filterId: e['filterViewId'] } }; //create a new delete FV request for each filter view present in sheet1
      }),
    },
    ssId
  );
}
```

The code is called before any method that depends on the filter views.

*Note:* This is a "fast & dirty" solution, use it at your own risk or rather do not use it at all:)

Comment: Three users viewing simultaneously can have the three different filterviews. So, ...

Comment: @TheMaster AppsScript runs for a certain user, hence it will be a matter of figuring out the active one for the user...

Comment: Could you share a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? That way the community could provide a better answer.

Comment: @GabrielCarballo Sure thing, provided above.

Answer (score 1):

Google Apps Script hasn't a method to get the active filter view, also, it's not possible to get the spreadsheet URL including the query string from client-side code `window.top.location` is blocked.

Regarding the "workarounds" using onOpen, if you mean the simple trigger it will not work for editors, as simple triggers run in limited-mode, meaning they can't execute methods that require authorization to run. By the other hand filter views are not user dependent if you remove them, the filter views are removed for all the spreadsheet users.

It looks that you have to think about a different way to do whatever you trying to do by detecting the active filter view.

Related

- [How can I set a filter view in a sheets script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29785482/1595451)
- [Switching between Filter views using apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42350431/1595451)

Comment: I have provided more context to the problem as well as the code - please have a look:) Any suggestions are very appreciated!