# Create a series of filter views based on a column of unique strings

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Sheet with 1000 rows. I am attempting to create a series of filter views based on the unique values found in a specific column.

I have it setup into two different sheets, one with the entirety of the data, and one that has progress shown and already has all of the unique values and count of those unique rows available (I omitted some of the actual data since it was irrelevant).

I know how to manually create a filter view, but is there a way I'd be able to just automate creating filter views by using the values located in Column A of the Progress sheet?

I made one view just to demonstrate I know how to do it (ie Data -> Filter Views -> Alerts) but I was hoping there was some function I could run that would create a new view for:

- Publication Groups
- Login
- Social
- ...etc

since they're all reliant on the same column being filtered. Any thoughts?

Here's the sample sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1flaKGUcY6V0jQ_wXKv-_AvOXQ5dmoD5WPbcUIQ810OI/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Nowadays the Sheets API supports filter views -> https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/filters

Answer (score -1):

I didn't need a filter view. I used the `UNIQUE` function to get the list and the `COUNTIF` function to count the occurances.

On your Progress worksheet in cell A2, use the formula

```
=UNIQUE(android_tests!A2:A376)
```

Then, in every cell in column B (bascially from B2:B376) use the formula

```
=COUNTIF(android_tests!$A$2:$A$376,A2)
```

Answer (score -1):

The script has no option to edit filter view, see [here](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/docs/ZIO2vp9r3aQ;context-place=forum/docs), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29785482/how-can-i-set-a-filter-view-in-a-sheets-script).

You may use a `filter` function + data validation with a list.

Use a filter on a separate sheet:

`=filter(Sheet1!A:Z, Sheet1!A:A = A1)`

In A1 use [Data Validation](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=Data%20validation%20list%20google%20sheets&oq=Data%20validation%20list%20google%20sheets&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60.8447j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) and link it to the unique list.