# Allow "Create New Filter View" feature on Google Sheet with some columns protected

Tags: google-sheets, filter, view

I am working on a large Google Sheet that has many editors from multiple companies, so I have had to give permissions on each tab on a per column basis. The issue is, because most editors only have editor access to 10-20% of the columns, the "Create New Filter View" feature is not working for those users. I am finding Filter View access to be very finicky in general. Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't on a sheet with similar protections. Other times "Create New Filter View" is not an available option, but if you select an existing filter view and click "Duplicate" you can create one. Seems like there are a few weird bugs with Google Sheets and permissions that I can't pin down.

Any ideas on how to use Apps Script to unlock the protections on the "Create New Filter View" option? This could be for all editors or all viewers, either would work in this instance. Thanks!

Comment: You cannot unlock a protection just for creating the filter view and not for the rest of actions. Also, in order to unlock the protection from the range, the script should act under the authority of a user who can edit that column. Probably the best way to go would be to create the filter view in a function that is triggered by an installed trigger. You could, for example, have an onEdit trigger so that, when a certain cell is edited, a new filter view is created. Do you think that would be an appropriate workaround? In this case, I'd consider posting an answer explaining this in more detail.

Comment: Thanks @Iamblichus. Not the answer that I was hoping for, but still good to get a clear answer on what is not possible. Google Sheets protections seem to be tricky to negotiate. I may have to do more tests on my end because I have one document where Filter Views work and a separate one with essentially the same protections setup where Filter Views does not and I can't seem to pin down what the issue is. If I can't suss it out, then I may have to settle for Temporary Filter View or an onEdit trigger like you mentioned (thanks for that idea as well!).

Answer (score 2):

#### Issue:

While a [FilterView](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/sheets#FilterView) can be [created](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/reference/rest/v4/spreadsheets/request#addfilterviewrequest) in a script if the [Advanced Sheets Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/advanced/sheets) is enabled, the same issue you're experiencing while creating it in the UI would show up here: **a user cannot create a `FilterView` if one of the columns is protected from this user**.

Naturally, this same user cannot run a script to unprotect the corresponding columns either - what worth would a protection be if the users to which it applies could remove it!

#### Possible workarounds:

A way around this would be to have a script that runs under the authority -see [getEffectiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser)- of a user who can edit those protected columns. In most situations, this is the user that is triggering the script -see [getActiveUser()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#geteffectiveuser)-, but in certain situations, like an [installable trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/understanding_triggers) or a web app that [executes as the user who deployed it](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web#legacy-editor), that is not the case.

For example, you could [install](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually) an [onEdit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) trigger with a user who has access to all the columns in the desired `FilterView`.

Then, this would fire whenever any user edits the spreadsheet, but it would fire under the authority of the user who installed the trigger (and can access the protected columns), so the `FilterView` could be created.

In order to create the `FilterView` only for certain edits (for example, when a specific cell is edited and there is a specific edited value), you could check these conditions at the beggining of the `onEdit` function. And if you needed to pass more information for customization of the filter view (for example, which columns and rows, which sheet, etc.), you could put that information in other cells and retrieve the corresponding values via `getValue()`/`getValues()`.

For example, It could be something like this:

```
function fireOnEdit(e) {
  if (e.range.getA1Notation() === "E1" && e.value === "Create FilterView") {
    const ss = e.source;
    const spreadsheetId = ss.getId();
    const sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
    const resource = {
      requests: {
        addFilterView: {
          filter: {
            range: {
              sheetId: sheet.getSheetId(),
              startRowIndex: 0,
              endRowIndex: 4,
              startColumnIndex: 0,
              endColumnIndex: 3
            }
          }      
        }
      }
    }
    Sheets.Spreadsheets.batchUpdate(resource, spreadsheetId);
  }
}
```